# Android карта этажа из svg изображения

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, map

Нужно сделать карту этажей здания в  android приложении. Библиотек на этот случай не нашел.

Изображение парсил с помощью библиотеки svg-android-2  (github).

Как лучше сделать svg изображение масшабируемым?
Как отследить нажание на определенную зону svg изображения?

Comment: Мне вот тоже интересен ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: Кажется вопрос достаточно понятен. Я уже писал ответ, как его закрыли. :(